# Determine the number of solutions of the equation $x^2+4x+6=\lambda e^x$

Tags: calculus

I'm asked to determine the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x^2+4x+6=\lambda e^x$$
To do that I study the function
$$\frac{x^2+4x+6}{e^x}$$
And I get this plot
[image: plot]
This way I can easly determine the number of solutions when changing $\lambda$.

Then I'm asked if I can demonstrate that
$$x^2+4x+6\ge 2(3-x)e^x$$
Which means
$$\frac{x^2+4x+6}{e^x} \ge 2(3-x)$$
If I draw the line 
$$y=-2x+6$$
I can see that's true. But how can I demonstrate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$g(x) = \frac{x^2+4x+6}{e^{x}}$$

$$g'(x) = \frac{e^x(2x+4)-(x^2+4x+6)e^x}{e^{2x}}=\frac{-x^2-2x-2}{e^x}$$

$$g''(x)=\frac{e^x(-2x-2)-e^x(-x^2-2x-2)}{e^{2x}}=\frac{x^2}{e^x} \ge 0$$

Hence the function $g$ is convex.

Now, let's compute the tangent of $g$ when $x=0$, we have $g(0)=6$ and $g'(0)=-2$.

Hence, the tangent is $$y=-2x+6.$$

Since it is a tangent, it lies below the convex curve, hence $g(x) \ge -2x+6$.